onnx, Error: Failed to load model because protobuf parsing failed
Iam trying to run a model using @xenova/transformers but getting the following error
Error: Failed to load model because protobuf parsing failed.
    at new OnnxruntimeSessionHandler (/root/moondream/node_modules/onnxruntime-node/dist/backend.js:27:92)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/root/moondream/node_modules/onnxruntime-node/dist/backend.js:64:29)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:483:21)
root@recollect-ubuntu-8gb-hel1-1:~/moondream# node index

this is the code
import {
  AutoProcessor,
  AutoTokenizer,
  Moondream1ForConditionalGeneration,
  RawImage,
} from "@xenova/transformers";

// Load processor, tokenizer and model
const model_id = "Xenova/moondream2";
try {
  const processor = await AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id);

  const tokenizer = await AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id);

  const model = await Moondream1ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    {
      dtype: {
        embed_tokens: "fp16", // or 'fp32'
        vision_encoder: "fp16", // or 'q8'
        decoder_model_merged: "q4", // or 'q4f16' or 'q8'
      },
      device: "cpu",
    }
  );

  // Prepare text inputs
  const prompt = "Describe this image.";
  const text = `<image>\n\nQuestion: ${prompt}\n\nAnswer:`;
  const text_inputs = tokenizer(text);

  // Prepare vision inputs
  const url =
    "https://huggingface.co/vikhyatk/moondream1/resolve/main/assets/demo-1.jpg";
 
  const image = await RawImage.fromURL(url);
  const vision_inputs = await processor(image);

  // Generate response
  const output = await model.generate({
    ...text_inputs,
    ...vision_inputs,
    do_sample: false,
    max_new_tokens: 64,
  });
  const decoded = tokenizer.batch_decode(output, { skip_special_tokens: false });
  console.log("answer new", decoded);
  // [
  //     '<|endoftext|><image>\n\n' +
  //     'Question: Describe this image.\n\n' +
  //     'Answer: A hand is holding a white book titled "The Little Book of Deep Learning" against a backdrop of a balcony with a railing and a view of a building and trees.<|endoftext|>'
  // ]
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error", error);
}

System :
node v22.4.0
ubuntu 24.04 LTS

The error seems to be raising at await Moondream1ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained
